# how to filter some fomat files while syncing to google drive

Tags: synchronization

How to stop syncing some format files ( for example .jpg or .png) to google drive. Because google drive by default syncing all the files and folder ( even hidden files ). So is there any way to not to sync some format files?

Comment: Are you syncing a folder using the API, or just with the regular Drive app?

Comment: syncing with regular Drive app.